# How to setup alerts for printers, toner low, etc? IPSwitch-What's Up?

Tags: snmp, alerts

I'm wanting to setup alerts for our printers so that when the printer encounters an error, it will send an alert to an email address.  Currently we have What's Up Standard, and it looks like you can do this in What's Up Premium.  Is there a way that i can use What's Up Standard, or any other tool, to set this up so that when PrinterX is low on Cyan it will send an alert to helpdesk@company.com?  Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From various Solaris administration docs, including [this one](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19082-01/819-7761/gfjhy/index.html):

> The following example shows how to set up the printer mars to send fault alerts by email to a user named joe, with reminders every 5 minutes.

`lpadmin -p mars -A 'mail joe' -W 5`

> The following example shows how to sets up the printer venus to send fault alerts to the console window, with reminders every 10 minutes.

`lpadmin -p venus -A write -W 10`

> The following example shows how to stop fault alerts for the printer mercury.

`lpadmin -p mercury -A none`

> The following example shows how to stop fault alerts until the printer venus has been fixed.

`lpadmin -p venus -A quiet`

Answer (score 0):

I use [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com) to handle this kind of thing.